# Binding an allocator to a custom token

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I would like to know how I can bind an allocator to a custom token of mine and use it in the token's  `async_result` implementation?

If we take `use_tuple` as an example, it seems to only work with its own `use_tuple.rebind(another_allocator)` allocator, and not with an allocator that has been associated by the user or the object of which the async function is called of?

In my own token for my own future type, I would like to be able to say

```
async_read(socket, buffer, bind_allocator(some_polymorphic_alloc, my::use_future));
```

And in my_use_future's `async_result<my::use_future_t, Signature>` specialization, I want to use the bound allocator. With `bind_allocator`, the async_read function uses that allocator for allocations. But I don't see a path where that allocator is passed down to my `my::use_future` token in its `async_result<>::initiate` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an introduction, `bind_allocator` and the completion token's internal allocator serve different purposes. I think it will become much clearer if I first address the questions in your post at face value:

1. > *I would like to know how I can bind an allocator to a custom token of mine [...]*

   It seems to me that `bind_allocator` already does what you ask:

   **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efcd9cc7edc96d77)**

   ```
   auto h = [](boost::system::error_code, size_t) {};
   asio::streambuf b(1024);

   std::allocator<char>             a1;
   pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> a2{pmr::get_default_resource()};

   async_read(s, b, h);
   async_read(s, b, asio::bind_allocator(a1, h));
   async_read(s, b, asio::bind_allocator(a2, h));
   async_read(s, b, asio::use_future);
   async_read(s, b, asio::bind_allocator(a1, asio::use_future));
   async_read(s, b, asio::bind_allocator(a2, asio::use_future));
   ```
2. > *[...] and use it in the token's async_result implementation?*

   You query it with [`get_associated_allocator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/get_associated_allocator.html).
3. > *But I don't see a path where that allocator is passed down to my my::use_future token in its async_result<>::initiate function.*

   That's because it isn't. [`bind_allocator(tok)` returns](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/bind_allocator.html) `allocator_binder< typename decay< T >::type, Allocator >`. This then is the token type. Therefore any composing operations will "see" your bound associator type, but *not* your token internally.

### How To Fix?

What you want is **not** merely an allocator associated with an allocator-agnostic completion token/handler. Rather you need an allocator-aware completion token.

You can create it like you would any classically allocator-aware type, e.g. for standard library types.

In fact, for example the `asio::use_future` token type is actually defined as `asio::use_future_t<std::allocator<void> >`.

As such it is both allocator-aware (the `async_result` specialization can respond to the chosen allocator type), **and** implements the [`associated_allocator` protocol](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/associated_allocator.html) to provide [`Handler` semantics](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html).

> I feel that the `associated_XXXX` protocol is closely inspired on the underused `std::uses_allocator` protocol. I'm using my own term "protocol" here to communicate that, in addition to an explicit trait type, there's a *convention* that plays together with the trait's primary template. But I digress.

---

### Side-note

Note that allocators are less strictly adhered to than say, bound executors. The latter are essential to program correctness. For allocators, the documentation states [_"Implementers can ignore the allocator, especially if the operation is not considered performance-sensitive"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/allocators.html).

Comment: Hm, I see. Thanks, I will provide an allocator to the token explicitly then.

Answer (score -1):

To bind an allocator to a custom token and use it in the token's async_result implementation, you need to pass the allocator to the token constructor and store it in the token. Then, when the async_result object is created, you can pass the stored allocator to the initiate function.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant Asio documentation or standards proposal where you can corroborate this theory?